# How to correctly harvest a published .NET 6 project?

Tags: wix4

I have a Windows service built in .NET 6 and want it installed with WiX. My project file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputName>Jenkins Log Collector Installer</OutputName>
    <EnableProjectHarvesting>false</EnableProjectHarvesting>
    <HarvestFileSuppressUniqueIds>false</HarvestFileSuppressUniqueIds>
    <HarvestFileGenerateGuidsNow>true</HarvestFileGenerateGuidsNow>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Variables.wxi" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="JenkinsLogCollector">
      <ComponentGroupName>LogCollectorFiles</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <BindPath Include="JenkinsLogCollector" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Heat" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Netfx.wixext" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.UI.wixext" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JenkinsLogCollector\JenkinsLogCollector.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And my Package.wxs looks like this:

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui" xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
  <?include Variables.wxi ?>
  <Package Name="$(var.ProductName)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="5d382d34-9f2f-42ed-a243-97bc91346970">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />

    <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck
      Property="DOTNETRUNTIMECHECK"
      Platform="x64"
      RollForward="major"
      RuntimeType="desktop"
      Version="6.0.0.0"
    />
    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="LogCollectorFiles" />
    </Feature>
    <ui:WixUI
      Id="WixUI_InstallDir"
      InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
      />
  </Package>
</Wix>
```

My issues are, well, many.

1. If I opt for project harvesting, I get the results of the build, not publishing. That means my main executable is a DLL and there's a whole lotta stuff added that I don't care about.
2. I can't find any information as to how to correctly define the path in `<HarvestDirectory>`. Using things like `$(JenkinsLogCollector.TargetPath)`, inspired by [this page from the official documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/msbuild/), causes Visual Studio to fail to load the project file.
3. In spite of the above, I would at least expect an error or an empty component group, but the `<HarvestDirectory>` tag does not even produce this much. As a result, the build complains that

> The identifier 'WixComponentGroup:LogCollectorFiles' could not be found.

What do I do? For a project that was so many years in development, it's silly that there's no usable documentation for building an installer, and I like to think that I'm not doing anything particularly odd here either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're telling HarvestDirectory to look for the files in the Setup project and not the JenkinsLogCollector project. Try changing

```
<HarvestDirectory Include="JenkinsLogCollector">
      <ComponentGroupName>LogCollectorFiles</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <BindPath Include="JenkinsLogCollector" />
```

to

```
<HarvestDirectory Include="..\JenkinsLogCollector\bin\Release\net6.0\publish">
      <ComponentGroupName>LogCollectorFiles</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <BindPath Include="..\JenkinsLogCollector\bin\Release\net6.0\publish" />
```

in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share with you an example of how I use HeatWave

```
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputName>App-Test</OutputName>
    <DefineConstants>
        ProductVersion=$(Version);
    </DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include=".\obj\$(Configuration)\publish\YourProject">
      <ComponentGroupName>HarvestedComponents</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <BindPath Include=".\obj\$(Configuration)\publish\YourProject" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Heat" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.UI.wixext" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\YourProject\YourProject.csproj" Publish="true" />
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The important thing here is `Publish="true"` in case anyone should overlook it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If I opt for project harvesting, I get the results of the build, not publishing. That means my main executable is a DLL and there's a whole lotta stuff added that I don't care about.

In order for Wix to publish your project, instead of building it, you will need to add the Publish attribute to your ProjectReference tag and to set it to true:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\JenkinsLogCollector\JenkinsLogCollector.csproj" Publish="true" />
```

> 2. I can't find any information as to how to correctly define the path in `<HarvestDirectory>`. Using things like `$(JenkinsLogCollector.TargetPath)`, inspired by [this page from the official documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/msbuild/), causes Visual Studio to fail to load the project file.

When using the above-mentioned Publish attribute, the resulting binaries will be put into `<your_installer_project_dir>\obj\<your_configuration_dirs>\publish\<your_published_project_name>\`. You can use MSBuild's `IntermediateOutputPath` property to dynamically generate the first part of this path:

```xml
<HarvestDirectory Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\publish\JenkinsLogCollector">
```

*Note: this code works for me, but [some people have had issues using backslashes instead of slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127565/15944706).*

> 3. In spite of the above, I would at least expect an error or an empty component group, but the `<HarvestDirectory>` tag does not even produce this much. As a result, the build complains that
>    The identifier 'WixComponentGroup:LogCollectorFiles' could not be found.

I've had the same issue and the only thing I've found regarding this comes from [the v3 documentation about heat](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/heat/), where it seems that defining the property `HarvestDirectoryVerboseOutput` as `true` should print additional informations. However, in my case, defining it this way did not change the output produced by heat (none).