# Installing .NET Runtime via WIX 4 Installer

Tags: .net, wix, wix4

I am using WIX 4 via the HeatWave Visual Studio extension to create an installer for my .NET 7 application. I would like the installer to automatically install .NET 7 runtime during the installation process, if it is not already installed on the machine.

I have used the information in this post: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/dotnet/ to display an error message if the runtime is not installed, but ideally I would like my installer to install it.

Comment: Did you solve this problem in the end? I'm also having the same issue.

Comment: I ended up following Christophers advice and published my app with a private self-contained .Net runtime.

Comment: How did you do that self contained runtime @codistavva?  Could you point me at a tutorial i can follow?    (I see that in VS you can right click > publish. But I dont understand how you get the result of that into the installer that WIX creates)

Comment: @Toby
Christopher provided a link below to his tutorial, which uses a self contained app:
https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/WiX-v4-HeatWave/web-api
The relevant part for publishing self contained is:
https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/blob/master/Images/web-api/apppublish5.png
I then configured Wix to harvest the publish directory using the HarvestDirectory tag in the Wix project file. 
Check the example here: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/heat/.

For troubleshooting:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74749469/how-to-use-harvestdirectory-in-wix-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much a pain these days.  You might want to consider just publishing you app with a private self-contained .net runtime.  The reason is the WiX community just can't keep up with the .NET team as the team is releasing about something like 15 installers every release and they are doing it once or twice a month.

I started this repos to collect these if anyone wants to contribute. One sample I have is Desktop Runtime 7.0.11 x64.   Created just two months ago, it's already two versions out of date.

https://github.com/iswix-llc/IsWiX.NetCore/blob/main/Installer/IsWiX.NetCore/Net7/DesktopRuntime/DesktopRuntime-x64-7.0.11.wxs

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
    <Fragment>
        <netfx:DotNetCoreSearch RuntimeType="desktop" MajorVersion="7" Platform="x64" Variable="DOTNETDESKTOPVERSION"/>
        <PackageGroup Id="DotNetDesktop7011Redist">
            <ExePackage Id="DotNetDesktop7011"
                        DetectCondition="DOTNETDESKTOPVERSION &gt;= &quot;7.0.11&quot;"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Vital="no"
                        InstallArguments="windowsdesktop-runtime-7.0.11-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart"
                        RepairArguments="windowsdesktop-runtime-7.0.11-win-x64.exe /repair /quiet /norestart"
                        UninstallArguments="windowsdesktop-runtime-7.0.11-win-x64.exe /uninstall /quiet /norestart">
                <ExePackagePayload
                            Description="Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime - 7.0.11 (x64)"
                            ProductName="Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime - 7.0.11 (x64)"
                            Name="windowsdesktop-runtime-7.0.11-win-x64.exe"
                            DownloadUrl="https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/2ce1cbbe-71d1-44e7-8e80-d9ae336b9b17/a2706bca3474eef8ef95e10a12ecc2a4/windowsdesktop-runtime-7.0.11-win-x64.exe"
                            Hash="c5f042dadd878e2cbd1833a73141e64fba2fae10ba5770daac8faf24bb56d7bc61cae8f7664c37fa822db71d0bf05b97733126db396e97e9ceeced596b9a63c1"
                            Size="57837864" 
                            Version="7.0.11.32825"
                            />
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose I will consider publishing my app with the runtime. Does this have to be done with a bootstrapper? I am having a really hard time finding documentation for this.

Comment: No, this is a setting you select when you publish your .net project.  It will output all the files needed to run the app without having .net installed globally.  See this tutorial for the concepts: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/WiX-v4-HeatWave/web-api