# How do I install .net core 6 with a WIX 4 installer?

Tags: .net-core, wix4

I am new to WIX and created a first installer which installs the application and other files, etc.

Now I want to add that .net Core 6 is installed as a prerequisite.

Is is correct that I need a Bundle for that and add my existing MSI into the Chain?

I looked at the WIX 3 examples but am not sure if they are still valid for WIX 4.
The WIX 4 examples and tutorials I found are only based on the Product element and Bundle is not mentioned.

I found this: [Installing .NET Runtime via WIX 4 Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430156/installing-net-runtime-via-wix-4-installer)
But it does not explain how to use it. I guess is need a Bundle to trigger the PackageGroup or can i add it to a Package?

Thanks, I really appreciate any help. I could not find much documentation on WIX 4. Especially which is helpful to a beginner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is indeed a *Bundle* installer.

Based on [Installing .NET Runtime via WIX 4 Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430156/installing-net-runtime-via-wix-4-installer)  I created a Fragment for the installers:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
 xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">

<Fragment>
    <netfx:DotNetCoreSearch RuntimeType="desktop" MajorVersion="6" Platform="x64" Variable="DOTNETDESKTOPVERSION" />
    <PackageGroup Id="DotNetDesktopRedist">
        <ExePackage Id="DotNetDesktop"
                    DetectCondition="DOTNETDESKTOPVERSION &gt;= &quot;6.0.27&quot;"
                    Permanent="yes"
                    Vital="no"
                    InstallArguments="windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart"
                    RepairArguments="windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe /repair /quiet /norestart"
                    UninstallArguments="windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe /uninstall /quiet /norestart">
            <ExePackagePayload
                Name="windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe"
                SourceFile="..\..\..\Packages\dotnet-runtime-win-x64\6.0.27\content\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe" />
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>


    <netfx:DotNetCoreSearch RuntimeType="aspnet" MajorVersion="6" Platform="x64" Variable="ASPDOTNETCOREVERSION" />
    <PackageGroup Id="AspNetCoreRedist">
        <ExePackage Id="AspNetCore"
                    DetectCondition="ASPDOTNETCOREVERSION &gt;= &quot;6.0.27&quot;"
                    Permanent="yes"
                    Vital="no"
                    InstallArguments="aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart"
                    RepairArguments="aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe /repair /quiet /norestart"
                    UninstallArguments="aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe /uninstall /quiet /norestart">
            <ExePackagePayload
                Name="aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe"
                SourceFile="..\..\..\Packages\aspnetcore-runtime-win-x64\6.0.27\content\aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.27-win-x64.exe" />
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

These *PackageGroup*s as well as the original installer msi are then used in the *Chain* element of the Bundle:

```
<Wix
xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

<?include Defines.wxi?>

<Bundle
    Name="$(var.ApplicationName)"
    Manufacturer="$(var.ManufacturerName)"
    Version="$(var.Version)"
    UpgradeCode="YourGUID">

    <BootstrapperApplication>
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="My Licensing Terms.rtf"
                                                Theme="rtfLicense" />
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="DotNetDesktopRedist" />
        <PackageGroupRef Id="AspNetCoreRedist" />
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\..\Build\Installer\en-US\Installer.msi" />
    </Chain>

</Bundle>
```

The elements of the *Chain* are executed in the given order.

Comment: You won't believe how long it took me to find this very useful information. Thanks a lot!